# Magento checkout.xml file not being recognised

Tags: xml, layout, magento

I've recently been building a Magento theme from scratch and have encountered a problem with the checkout.xml file. It doesn't seem to be recognised by the system. The reason I say this is that I was trying to comment out the following code to remove the My Cart and Checkout links from the top menu.

```
<action method="addCartLink"></action>
<action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
```

This should remove the links but wouldn't. I even deleted all the code from the file and saved it to see if it would break the system or bring up any errors, to no avail. I managed to remove the links using the following code in the customer.xml file, but still feel I should know why the problematic file is not being recognised to develop an understanding of Magento.

```
<remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
```

I will add that these layout files were added to the layout folder after I initially installed the theme, but this shouldn't be a problem as all worked fine in the customer.xml file, yet not the checkout.xml. I also cleared the cache in the backend. This did not work.

Any ideas would be seriously appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on how the [layout system works](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates), and then use the mentioned [Layout Viewer](http://alanstorm.com/2005/projects/MagentoLayoutViewer.tar.gz) to debug your layout.

My first three guesses

1. Clear your cache (which you did, but layout viewer will let you know what Magento is actually seeing)
2. You're editing the wrong checkout.xml (easy to do when you start adding multiple themes by copying the old)
3. There's another block that's adding those links

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and found problem on our host, I made some changes in checkout.xml and lost the checkout functionality, I was sure that what I did was correct.

Problem was file permission issue. when I modify any file on server its permission changed to 644 so to fix that I changed the permission to 755 and all is fine with my updates :)

Comment: I feel your pain with file permissions dude. :P